# How to turn camera into ONVIF IP Device?

Tags: pi-3, picamera

I am new to Raspberry Pi and also new to ONVIF.
I can you turn a raspberry pi camera into ONVIF compatible IP camera and also add different profiles and edit the features in the profiles.

I don't know where or how to start his project.

I've trawled the internet and found this link
https://github.com/BreeeZe/rpos
It appears that this is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Unfortunately, I don't know where to start with any of these instructions in the link.

Can you Please direct me in right direction?

Comment: Start with *STEP 1 - CONFIG RASPBERRY PI* ... then continue ... looks pretty simple - to be honest

Comment: How to add different ONVIF profiles to the camera?

Comment: "It implements the key parts of Profile S and Profile T" - what other profiles were you considering?

Comment: I should be able to edit the features in the profiles as per requirement.
which is the code I should make changes in and what changes should be done ?

Comment: Oh, I don't think what you found does what you want, it does what they want

Comment: yes. Can you direct me in right direction from where to start from?